# LINQ to XML how to get the child of the root and then descendents?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML Schema Defined Like this:

```
<PeopleContainer>
  <People>
    <Person Name="John Doe" Age="27" CauseOfAwesome="King of All Cosmos" />
    <Person Name="Ally McBeagle" Age="7" CauseOfAwesome="Adorable" />
    <Person Name="Bender Rodriguez" Age"249" CauseOfAwesome="Bending" />  
  </People>
</PeopleContainer
```

What I want to do is grab the People tag as an `IEnumerable` so that I can pipe it into my application, but I haven't seen an option for this case yet.

I've been trying something like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var people = from p in xdoc.Descendants("People")
             select new
             {
               Name = p.Attribute("Name").Value,
               Age = p.Attribute("Age").Value,
               CauseOfAwesome = p.Attribute("CauseOfAwesome")
             };
foreach (var p in people)
{
   Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

I think I may be instantiating `people` incorrectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have forgotten to set Element Person:

```
        var people = from p in xdoc.Root.Descendants("People")
            select new
            {
                Name = p.Element("Person").Attribute("Name").Value,
                Age = p.Element("Person").Attribute("Age").Value,
                CauseOfAwesome = p.Element("Person").Attribute("CauseOfAwesome")
            };

        foreach (var n in people)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(n.Age);
            Console.WriteLine(n.CauseOfAwesome);
        }
```